# I'm running hive 2.1.1, hadoop 2.3.0 on windows 10

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

i have problem when i am trying to write HiveQL query with aggregation function or join this Warnning appear  :
WARNING: Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.

--->So i want to run Spark as a engine instead of MapReduce on hive , I'm running hive 2.1.1, hadoop 2.3.0 on windows 10.
is that the solution or there is another solution to this issue ?

Comment: Good Luck with that...
:)

Comment: I think you need to ask a question.

Comment: By the way, Tez runs faster under conditions with less memory  (and has been supported for longer, and is quicker to install)... Hive on Spark isn't feature complete according to the Hive wiki... If you just want to write SQL, then you can install Spark alone and run Spark Thrift Server, and you don't need Hive